# Using TweenMax to fade in div with background pattern and z-index not working

Tags: javascript, css, tween, gsap

I'm trying to do this really simple fade using TweenMax for this div I have. Here's the css for the div

```
.aboutBg { 
    background:url(../images/pattern.jpg);
    top:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0,
    position:fixed;
    border:10px solid red;
    z-index:10;
}

TweenMax.to('.aboutPage', 0.5, {autoAlpha:1});
```

What's happening is the border would fade in nicely but the patterned bg is not, it just pops up at the end of the tween. If I remove the z-index everything works, but I have to have set the z-index so it's on top of my other content. Also I'm not tweening the z-index, it's set before the tween, so I'm not sure why it's not fading correctly. Anyone has any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Which browser? I had a similar problem with safari recently... a `z-index: x !important;` CSS declaration saved the day for me.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you've upgraded to the last version of TweenMax. Second, use alpha instead of autoAlpha and tell if there's a difference.

Comment: hmm still doing the same thing after changing it to alpha.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed two things:

1. You named your class "aboutBg" but your tween is referencing "aboutPage"
2. You've got a comma after "bottom:0" instead of a semicolon.

I corrected those and it worked fine for me. If you're still having trouble, please let us know what browser you're using and create a codepen or jsfiddle that clearly demonstrates the issue so we can take a peek in context. And like the previous post said, please make sure you're using the latest version of TweenMax. http://www.greensock.com/?download=GSAP-JS